# How to autocomplete a <li> with <a>

Tags: html-lists, jquery-autocomplete

I have generated a list with links inside in hierarchy. I am trying to make a form/input to let people type in words and it fetch the list(in hierarchy) with autocomplete. The autocomplete results are links. Any help would be great. Thanks

Something like this

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="#">1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the autocomplete strings in an array using a JQuery selector and a `map` function

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = $('ul > li > a').map(function() {
    return this.href;
  }).toArray();

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label>Items autocomplete</label>
<input id="tags" type="text" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="results_count"></span>

<p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="aaaa">1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="aabb">1.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aacc">1.2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="aabb">1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="bbcc">1.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aabc">1.2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

EDIT: second version where autocomplete uses the text in the `<li>`'s

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = $('ul > li > a').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).toArray();

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label>Items autocomplete</label>
<input id="tags" type="text" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="results_count"></span>

<p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="aaaa">xxxx</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="aabb">xxyy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aacc">xxzz</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="aabb">xxyy</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="bbcc">yyzz</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aabc">xxyz</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/DLLVw/1180/)

Comment: Thanks for that, it is possible to have the autocomplete to pick up the words in the <li> instead ?And have the results display as the li text with the links?

Comment: Thank you for the second version, it works well, but is it possible to have them display in text with links?

Comment: @williamchan04 I'm not sure I understand what you mean, where do you want to display the links?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I want the auto complete to be the text with link <a href="aaaa">xxxx</a> so they can click on it

Answer (score 0):

see datalist and list in html5 
[datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but would it work with links? I want the <a>to wrap the <li>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = $('ul > li > a').map(function() {
  console.log($(this));
    return {
    label: $(this).text(), 
    value: $(this).attr('href')
    };  
  }).toArray();
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, target) {
      var link = target.item.value;
      console.log(link);
        location.href = link;
    }
  });

});
```